# what is wrong with the following implementation of Conv1d?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I am trying to implement a `Conv1d` layer with Batch Normalization but I keep getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ef6e122ea50c> in <module>()
----> 1 test()
      2 for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
      3   train(epoch)
      4   test()

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    258                             _single(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    259         return F.conv1d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 260                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    261 
    262     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [25, 40, 5], but got 2-dimensional input of size [32, 40] instead
```

The data is passed on in batches of 32 using DataLoader class and it has 40 features and 10 labels. Here is my model:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        #self.flatten=nn.Flatten()
        self.net_stack=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=40, out_channels=25, kernel_size=5, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(25, affine=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=25, out_channels=20, kernel_size=5, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(20, affine=True),
            nn.Linear(20, 10),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1))

    def forward(self,x):
        #x=torch.reshape(x, (1,-1))
        result=self.net_stack(x)
        return result
```

I have tried given in other answers like unsqueezing the input tensor, but none of the models in such questions is using Conv1d with batchnorm1d so I am not able to narrow down the problem to which layer must be causing the error. I have just started with using Pytorch and was able to implement a simple linear NN model, but I am facing this error while using a convolutional NN for the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a batch dimension to your input (and also change the number of input channels).

A `conv1d` layer accepts inputs of shape `[B, C, L]`, where `B` is the batch size, `C` is the number of channels and `L` is the width/length of your input. Also, your `conv1d` layer expects 40 input channels:

```
nn.Conv1d(in_channels=40, out_channels=25, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
```

hence, your input tensor `x` must have shape `[B, 40, L]` while now it has shape `[32, 40]`.

Try:

```
def forward(self,x):
    result=self.net_stack(x[None])
    return result
```

you will get another error complaining about dimensions mismatch, suggesting you need to change the number of input channels to 40.

Comment: Yes I got the error `Given groups=1, weight of size [25, 40, 5], expected input[1, 32, 40] to have 40 channels, but got 32 channels instead`, I am using a batch size of 32 for training, and as you can see I have set the input channels to 40 in the Conv1d  layer. the features that the data has are 40 so that's why I kept the `in_channels=40`. As you said, the current shape of x is `[32,40]` but it needs to have the `L` term in it too, how do I do that?

Comment: If your data has 40 features, then L=40. Instead, the number of input channel is 1. This means that your input size should be: [32, 1, 40]. Also, you need to change the line that defines the conv1d layer into: nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=25, kernel_size=5, stride=2)

Comment: so that means I should change the first Conv1d layer to be : `nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1, out_channels=25, kernel_size=5, stride=2)`?

Comment: Okay didn't see you edited your comment, will try and let you know

Comment: I did that, I now get the error `Given groups=1, weight of size [25, 1, 5], expected input[1, 32, 40] to have 1 channels, but got 32 channels instead`. I was looking at how can I change the input size but most of them were related to changing the input shape for transfer learning. Can you please let me know how do I do that? I am new to Pytorch so I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: A quick solution is to write: `result=self.net_stack(x[:, None, :])`. A better solution would change the dataloader code. If this answer helped you, can you plase accept it?

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot! That error is resolved now, I am getting another error `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (640x7 and 20x10)` which is probably because of the Linear layer and I am trying to resolve that now

Comment: this is a different issue. If you have problem with that, please, open a new question. Thank for accepting my answer!

Comment: Hi Neb, the model was working fine now, but I was just hoping you could explain what `net_stack` signifies, because the autograder is throwing a Key error which has the word net_stack in it for the keys so I think maybe it's causing a problem.

Comment: `net_stack` is not a particular name in python or pytorch. It is most likely an error due to how you wrote your app. I suggest you to open a new question for this.